# Generate unique number from Button Click

Tags: c#, guid

I'm attempting to generate a unique number (which will be used as an identity number to a row in a DataTable) For a stock order application, where I enter a stock item number, select a supplier, and click "order" and it generates the number, and enters it into a new data row under a column called "Order Number".
I understand that GUID can do what I need, but it generates a number thats too long, and are random. I require sequential numbers (e.g : 1,2,3,4).

Comment: *'random and not in sequence, which I require'* can't read your thoughts - what sequence you require? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Wait... You need a sequential number? Why don't you just use an auto-increment field on the database?

Comment: I meant as in order, e.g 1,2,3,4..

Comment: So then a GUID doesn't do what you need.

Comment: has a long Count that initialize as 0 and increased by 1 everytime you click it?

Comment: @PMF I think that is what i'm after, can you write it as an answer so I can select that as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a database is being used to store orders, use an order-ID [identity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) column - for example:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Orders
(
    OrderID into IDENTITY(1,1),
    -- other columns
)
```

If not (which seems unlikely), use a singleton or static order-number generator that returns the max order number returned previously plus one.

You could implement this max-plus-one logic in the button-click event handler too of course, but I would just plan on order-number generation as a responsibility to encapsulate in a distinct type.

Comment: Note that the latter option will requires proper threading to be considered (like using interlocked increments)

Comment: @zespri:  Absolutely.

Comment: I assume that auto-increment field is different to having the data type as int and set to identifier?

Comment: I think you may be confusing terminology.  T-SQL `IDENTITY` is the means to specify auto incrementation for an `int` column.  In a SQL Server context, "Identifier" only brings to mind `uniqueidentifier`, which is the SQL Server GUID data type.

Comment: I am confused yes, I think I'll stick to setting the data type as an int with identity set to true.

Comment: "..."[i]dentifier"...."

Comment: So the identity for an int column isn't the same as a uniqueidentifier?

Comment: @user3237403: No, they are not the same. `int` and `uniqueidentifier` are data types that columns can have. `IDENTITY` is a column property, applicable to columns with numeric data types.  A [SQLTeam blog post](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/understanding-identity-columns) provides a nice overview of identity columns and details on applicable numeric data types.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a sequential number, you don't need a GUID, you should do that in your database.